# How Can I Share Referenced Resources Between PDF Files

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I create hundreds of PDF files with the same images and fonts. I there a way I can share these resources between all the files instead of having them embedded in each PDF? It sure would be a disk space saver.

Comment: I doubt it -- doing that would negate the Portable in "Portable Document Format".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  PDFs are meant to be stand-alone files which fully encompass font information, vector graphics and whatnot in a single file.  Sharing between files would break this.  If you're looking to save space (and application requirements), you might consider generating the PDFs on the fly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Makes perfect sense now that I think about it! These PDFs are delivered to a client either on CD or as a ZIP file download. Any other ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's probably your best bet.  Hopefully they compress well.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed external links for things like files if you just want to share linked files.